# How to use sleep(or something similar to sleep) with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, thread-sleep

I'm using java swings for my application. Below is the piece of my code. However I know that `Thread.sleep()` should not be used with swings. I read some posts that says to use `Timer` from `javax.swing.timer` But for the below code I do not know how to implement it.

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
     try{
        demo.main("Welcome");
        Thread.sleep(900);
        demo.main("Argument to main");
        Thread.sleep(900);
        demo.main("Argument to main");

        // after this I call a method say `xyz` which also uses Thread.sleep() 
        // and this `xyz` method uses variables that are updated in `demo.main()`

       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

How can I implement the same behaviour as sleep?

EDIT:

- `demo.main()` doesnot update GUI, But `xyz()` updates GUI depending
  variables updated in `demo.main()`
- I want to call `demo.main()` at first when the mouse is clicked and after a minute I want to call it again and again after a minute. And after the completion of this I want to call another method `xyz()` which also uses `thread.sleep()` and uses variables updated in `demo.main()`

Comment: What exactly is it, that you want to achieve? Do you want to trigger an event after a given arbitrary time, or do you actually want to wait for another event to happen, before you do a corresponding action? For example: Do you want to wait for a prepared connection before sending a message, or do you want to send a message 1 minute after starting the application, assuming, that the connection is ready?

Comment: Use a Swing based `Timer` to move through the relevant messages. It ensures calls to update the UI are done on the EDT.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Yes, well we have no idea what demo.main() does. If it updates a component on the GUI then you should use a Swing Timer. If it doesn't update the GUI then you can use other approaches.

Comment: @camickr Edited the post

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `ScheduledExecutorService` and an ordered list of actions. Using `enum` is good for this. This `enum` could then implement a simple functional `interface`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

enum ClickAction {
    Action1(900) {
        @Override
        void execute() {
            message("Welcome");
        }

    },
    Action2(900) {
        @Override
        void execute() {
            message("Another message");
        }

    };
    private final int delayAfter;

    private ClickAction(int delayAfter) {
        this.delayAfter = delayAfter;
    }

    abstract void execute();
}

private static void message(String msg) {
    System.out.println("msg=" + msg);
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int delay = 0;
    for (ClickAction action : ClickAction.values()) {
        // Schedule it.
        executor.schedule(() -> {
            action.execute();
        }, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        // Add up all of the delays.
        delay += action.delayAfter;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should do the trick, but `mouseClicked()` should check, that the same action isn't scheduled several times, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply spawn off a new thread e.g. (the simplest example)

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     demo.main("Welcome");
     Thread.sleep(900);
     demo.main("Argument to main");
     Thread.sleep(900);
     demo.main("Argument to main");
   }
});
t.start();
```

since you don't want block the Swing update thread (as you've noted). The above will invoke your `demo` class in a background thread. I would perhaps investigate [Java multithreading further](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html) - if you have more complex requirements you may wish to use higher level constructs than the simple `Thread` object presented here.

Comment: I want to call another method after "demo.main" which uses variables updated in "demo.main". If I call that method after the thread, both will execute concurrently and the variable updated will not be visible here

Comment: I think that's perhaps a different question, and I've provided a link to a multithreading tutorial which may be of use

Answer (score 0):

`CountDownLatch` may do what you want.

For example:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    try{
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        demo.main("Welcome", latch);
        latch.await();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then in main you would call `latch.countDown()` to continue beyond the await.

Comment: I have not worked with `CounDownLatch` before. And I want to perform all the operation when mouse is clicked. So where should I call `latch.countDown()`  ? @Freddie Coleman